# Where does the energy go in such an interaction?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

Suppose we have magnet which attracts some body made of iron. So the body makes some work while moving (it moves because magnet attracts it). So it became able to make work, because it received potential energy because of the attraction of the magnet. But by the law of conservation of energy, energy doesn't appear and doesn't disappear so where the energy was taken? Maybe I interpret law of conservation wrong  ?

Comment: You will need energy to restore the original configuration

Comment: It smells like homework. But can't you guess where energy goes when two things smack together? Where does the energy go when the same iron object falls to the floor? Hint: What do you hear? What does the nice soft floor material look like after the nasty hard iron bar hits it?

Comment: @puppetsock No, I meant that, when we had magnet and body far enough, body had no potential energy, but when we put them one near the other, body gained potential energy. Where did the energy body gained appear ? And no, it is not a homework.

Comment: The body *loses* potential energy getting closer to the magnet. That potential energy turns into kinetic energy, which turns into heat and sound when the bodies collide.

Comment: @HiddenBabel Yes, but in the beginning, body gained potential energy from some source. And we can say that magnet was the source because it caused the attraction, but doesn't this mean that energy just appeared ?

Comment: The energy you think is missing was stored in the magnetic field; note that electromagnetic fields possess an energy density.

Comment: @aghostinthefigures Then, this solves my question, but then, another question appears for me, does the field lose its energy when interacting ?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош In this specific case, the energy density of the electromagnetic field changes as the iron moves towards the magnet because the field itself changes as the iron moves towards the magnet. The precise statement describing the energy change of an electromagnetic field is called Poynting’s theorem, and is also indirectly responsible for enabling Joule heating (what makes toaster coils get hot when you run current through them).